Does "less" have "--retry" option like "tail"?
I'm using less to continuously trace Squid log file (as well as UFW log) with this command:
less --follow-name -K +F /var/log/squid/access.log

And at the time of rotation of Squid log less quits. I guess this happens because when an old file is renamed the new one is not created immediately but with a delay, though in the case of UFW log file this doesn't happen and less successfully switches to the new file.
So is there a method or option to make less wait for a new file to appear?

I can't reproduce the behaviour you're describing with less version 643 on Debian testing. Where I do see it waiting for the file to reappear whether I rename or delete the original.

@StéphaneChazelas I'm on Ubuntu 24.04.1, less is 590 (all the latest updates are installed). If I get it right less is a system package and for some reason the latest available version is from 2021. How can I manually upgrade less to the latest version?

FWIW, I can't reproduce with 590 nor 418 either. Can you describe a modus operandi where you manage to reproduce the issue. For instance, with seq 1000 > file; less --follow-name -K +F file, and then from another terminal rm file or mv file file2, and then seq 100 > file I can't reproduce it.

The closest I can get to your issue is if I recreate the file with it being inaccessible like with (umask 666; seq 100 > file) in which case less issues a file: Permission denied  (press RETURN) and exits when I press Return

@StéphaneChazelas I just run the command less --follow-name -K +F /var/log/squid/access.log and less successfully shows me the log file but when I open the console tab shortly after midnight I see less quit and I have to run the command again.

Do you have any options set in the LESS environment variable?

@StephenKitt Just checked /etc/environment — there's no LESS in it.

@EliiO Is LESS listed by the env command?

@Kusalananda I see LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s and LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s Is this it?

No, the LESS variable would show up as LESS= in env’s output. That’s fine, I just wanted to check whether you had options set there that might interfere with -K or +F; you don’t.

If tail --retry does work you can just pipe that into less instead of opening the file directly:
tail -F /var/log/squid/access.log | less


Can you please write an example of how can I do it on Ubuntu?

@StephenKitt, thank you, I added the options from my initial command to less (tail -F /var/log/squid/access.log | less -K +F) and it seems now less doesn't quit on log rotation and keeps following the new file.
